# Xamarin .Form unhandled exception Java.lang.NumberformatException: Invalid int:

Tags: c#, sqlite, exception, xamarin

I'm new in Xamarin. I want to learn about Sqlite and implement on my project.Yesterday I don't received any error and it's worked.Today i continue my project.But when i started compiled, an exception handing error message appear.I don't know what mistake I make. Hope you guys can help me solve this problem.

[image: asd]

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.IO;

namespace TravellerApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "TravellerApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            //initialize Forms map
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);


            string fileName = "travel_db.sqlite";
            string folderPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);

            LoadApplication(new App(fullPath));
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TravellerApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static string DatabaseLocation = string.Empty;

        public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

        }

        public App(String databaseLocation)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //MainPage = new TravelRecordApp.MainPage();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

            DatabaseLocation = databaseLocation;
        }

        protected override void OnStart ()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep ()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume ()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show use the value of fullpath before the crash? It's needed

Comment: "/data/data/com.companyname.TravellerApp/files/travel_db.sqlite"